# Bacteria genetic screen for mutants

Tags: genetics

Is there a simple screen for bacterial mutants with increased mutation rates? For example, detection of some loss-of-function mutation that causes increased mutation rates.

Any screen I can think of (for example, just testing on several different selective mediums) would select for bacteria with several mutations, but that does not necessarily imply an increased mutation rate.

Answer (score 0):

You may give a look at the Ames test, and possibly adapt it to your needs. Basically, the test was developed to identify genotoxic substances, i.e. substances that increased mutation rates in bacteria.
The standard way is to use strains of bacteria that are classified as His-, i.e. they need an external source of Histidine to survive.
In the Ames test you prepare two cultures of such bacteria. One of them is exposed to the hypothetical mutagen, and one acts as a control. You grow both of them in plates with minimal amount of Histidine, so that all bacteria grow for a while.
When Histidine is over, only the revertant mutants will survive. If the hypothetical substance is a mutagen, you should notice that in the corresponding plate there are more revertant.
This can be easily adapted to your case if your strain are His- (or can be convinced to become His-) or have some other identifiable mutation.
So, assuming that you are happy to compare mutation rates in a series of strains that are His-, you just need to compare the growth of those strains on minimal histidine and the faster growers are likely those with the higher mutation rate, according to Ames postulate.
If your strain do not have such a property, it may be more difficult (and actually, I wouldn't know what to do, right now!)